# SSRS Report Execution Service Render to Image High DPI and Image Rendering Small

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

We have service which renders SSRS reports to images, by default these are rendered at 96dpi by the ReportExecutionService, which is too low quality.

Increasing the DPI using the following deviceInfo string in the render method improves the quality of the text etc.

```
deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>TIFF</OutputFormat><PrintDpiX>384</PrintDpiX><PrintDpiY>384</PrintDpiY><DpiX>384</DpiX><DpiY>384</DpiY></DeviceInfo>"


results = rsExec.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, "", "", null, null)
```

However this results in any images on the report set to 'Original Size' to appear much smaller than they would if the report was viewed on the report server or in the report viewer.

Increasing the images DPI or setting to Fit Proportional isnt really an option as we do not have full control over the reports themselves

Comment: If the images you mention are external or embedded images, then I think you will have to create new copies of them at a higher DPI, otherwise you are taking the same image but squeezing it into a smaller physical area because you increased the report DPI.

Comment: Using EMF instead of TIFF seems to fix this issue but i can only render one page at a time, this causes a bit of a performance issue when rending reports with lots of pages

Comment: The are a lot of references to blog posts on EMF and Persisting Streams for multi page reports on the various other forumns but the links are all dead.

Comment: Can you not create higher DPI versions of your images and swap them out for the ones you have?

Comment: We dont have control over the images